# How do you attributes into form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a view that has the following inside a `form_tag`

```
<%= text_field_tag(:email) %>
```

Which, when form is submitted. Sends `params[:email]` to the controller.

How do I make sure it sends `params[:attributes][:email]` instead?

Comment: Try `text_field_tag 'attributes[email]'`

Comment: Or `text_field_tag 'attributes[email]', <existing_value>`

Comment: Thanks, if one of you could leave it as an answer. I will select is as such

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 text_field_tag :'post[attributes][email]'  // replace post name according to yours.
```

Comment: conversion to a symbol is unnecessary. Also the OP said nothing about enclosing this in `post`